# Call a method with params that do nothing in a smart contract

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I'm trying to **invoke a method with parameters that do nothing (blank body) in a smart contract** but that doesn't work even if the contract is correctly deployed to the blockchain.

Use case:
Smart contract contains a method:

```
# params :  sp.record(a = 3, b = 6, c = 9)
methodToBeCalled(self, params)
```

When I try to create a test scenraio in the smart contract  methodToBeCalled(a: 3, b: 6, c: 9) I got this error:

> Error: Error in Scenario 
>   Type Error 
>   sp.TRecord(a = sp.TIntOrNat, b = sp.TIntOrNat) is not sp.TUnit 
>   Bad params type sp.record(a: 3, b: 6, c: 9)

So Is it possible to create a method that don't use it's parameters (blank method) just like:

```
@sp.entry_point
    def Amethod(self, params):
    # params type is record: {a: 3, b: 6, c: 9}
    return
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said on telegram, you need to put a type constraint. Otherwise, `params` is inferred to be of type unit. You can use this command:

```
sp.set_type(params, sp.TRecord(a = sp.TIntOrNat, b = sp.TIntOrNat))
```